# What encoding is used for the keys when using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`?

Tags: ssl, openssh

When I run:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

to generate a public/private key pair in files e.g. id_rsa.pub and id_rsa, my understanding is that the public key encodes a prime number p, and the private key encodes a number pq. But when I open these files I don't see human-readable numbers, I see sequences of characters. So my question is simply: what am I looking at? Are these characters directly mappable to numbers and, if so, by what convention/algorithm/encoding?

Comment: An RSA keypair generates _two_ primes (p and q) and their product n = pq. The public key consists of n and e, the public exponent; the private key must include n and d, the private exponent, but in practice also include p, q, and several additional numbers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Key_generation .

Comment: Computers only store numbers as ASCII digits if humans need to read them, otherwise more space efficient methods are available.  The Base64 is a mapping onto visible ASCII characters so they could go through any kind of ASCII-based (7-bit) mail system without being distorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The  `ssl` keys (private and public) are usually stored in so named [PEM format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail).

> Privacy-Enhanced Mail (PEM) is a de facto file format for storing and
>   sending cryptographic keys, certificates, and other data, based on a
>   set of 1993 IETF standards defining "privacy-enhanced mail." While the
>   original standards were never broadly adopted, and were supplanted by
>   PGP and S/MIME, the textual encoding they defined became very popular.
>   The PEM format was eventually formalized by the IETF in RFC 7468.

This format is actually header, then [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded binary data and footer.

> Base64 is a group of similar binary-to-text encoding schemes that
>   represent binary data in an ASCII string format by translating it into
>   a radix-64 representation. The term Base64 originates from a specific
>   MIME content transfer encoding. Each Base64 digit represents exactly 6
>   bits of data. Three 8-bit bytes (i.e., a total of 24 bits) can
>   therefore be represented by four 6-bit Base64 digits.

For `ssh` keys please check below from dave_thompson_085 comments:

> Note ssh-keygen uses (several) PEM formats but never the one(s) in
>   7468. In the past for RSA it defaulted to OpenSSL's two 'traditional' (aka 'legacy') formats, either unencrypted whcih is 7468-like except
>   containing PKCS1, or password-encrypted which is1421-like with
>   Proc-type and DEK-Info and base64 of encrypted PKCS1, but not
>   7468-like. Since 7.8 it defaults to OpenSSH's own 'new format'
>   (previously invoked by option -o) which is 7468-like but the contents
>   are entirely different (XDR-style not ASN.1). There are numerous Qs
>   about these already on several Stacks.
>
> OpenSSH public key formats are never PEM (although commercial 'SSH2'
>   sort-of are), just base64 of SSH wire format. And I was recently
>   reminded [this Q/A](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39279/stronger-encryption-for-ssh-keys) covers the private key formats quite thoroughly

Comment: Note ssh-keygen uses (several) PEM formats but never the one(s) in 7468. In the past for RSA it defaulted to OpenSSL's two 'traditional' (aka 'legacy') formats, either unencrypted whcih is 7468-like except containing PKCS1, or password-encrypted which is1421-like with Proc-type and DEK-Info and base64 of encrypted PKCS1, but not 7468-like. Since 7.8 it defaults to OpenSSH's own 'new format' (previously invoked by option `-o`) which is 7468-like but the contents are entirely different (XDR-style not ASN.1). There are numerous Qs about these already on several Stacks.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thank you for clarification. May I quote you comment in my answer?

Comment: Soitenly; you don't really need to ask, as Stack is always CC-BY-SA+attribution but I'm happy to confirm that. I forgot to add that OpenSSH _public_ key formats are never PEM (although _commercial_ 'SSH2' sort-of are), just base64 of SSH wire format. And I was recently reminded https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39279/stronger-encryption-for-ssh-keys covers the private key formats quite thoroughly.